# Optimal triangulation of convex polygon - longest diagonal is smallest

Tags: algorithm

I'm given `n` set of points `v_1=<x_1,y_1>,...,v_n=<x_n,y_n>`, such that they create a convex polygon, and I need to find an optimal triangulation of it. Optimal triangulation has the largest diagonal being the smallest possible.

It's not a traditional triangulation problem, since we don't minimize sum of lengths of diagonals, but the minimum length of the longest diagonal.

But the reasoning is the same, right?

We have `m[i][j]`- minimal maximum diagonal in subpolygon `v_i->v_j`

`m[i][i+1]=0`

`m[i][j]=min( for k = i+1 to j-1 => MAX(m[i][k],m[k][j],|v_k v_j|,|v_i v_k|))`

Where `|v_k v_j|`- distance between those two vertices.

Correct?

Comment: Looks good, except that you should include some more base cases: `m[i][i+2] = |v_i v_{i+2}|` (for cutting off an "ear").